# Call an action on button click in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action defined in my lib directory. The action is used to send a get request in the server. I want to execute the function on button click. How can I do this? I know this is not the right approach. I am new to rails.

show_document.rb (in lib directory)

```
class Legaldoc::ShowDocument

def view_document(sessionID, token_document)
    require 'rest-client'
    require 'zip'
    res = RestClient::Request.execute(
        :method => :get,
        :url => "http://myurl.com",
        :headers => {
            :ldsessionId => sessionID,
        }
    )
  end
end
```

in my view file

```
<%= link_to 'Button', '#', :onclick => "view_document(sessionID, token_document)" %>
```

Comment: Your page needs to fire a request to your rails app. During handling of this request, your app will call your method. Rails' `button_to` could be useful: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

Answer (score 5):

I know this is confusing when you start developing in rails, but you have to consistently be very aware *where* your code is running. Your ruby code runs on the server, your html/js runs in the browser. Rails "prepares" html/js, but when you click a button, and you have to ask something from the server, you will have to use a *url* to acces a/any server.

Or you could resort to using javascript on the client directly, to fetch the data.

But since you already have the code in `lib` you will have to

- add an endpoint, aka an action in a controller (add a new controller or add a new action in an existing controller, that is a bit hard with so little background information)
- add a route to that controller/action
- add the controller-code to call your lib function and format the answer in such a way relevant for the user

then add the button as follows:

```
 <%= link_to 'Button', my_action_controller_path(session_id: sessionId, token_document: token_document) %>
```

(the name of the path depends on the names of controller/action, and you can see the names of the routes by running `rake routes`)

*However*  your code seems to just fetch a page at `myurl.com`, so you could also just build a link to `myurl.com` ?

```
<%= link_to 'Button', 'http://myurl.com', target: '_blank' %>
```

Comment: I think that the special little sessionID header is a key piece to the puzzle here and the reason he can't just use a link.